# What is flawed about my delegated event handling on this carousel code?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, events

I have a page that I'm loading through AJAX. Everything is working on that page *except* this carousel: http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/n0v1sLk4/1/

When the carousel is loaded through AJAX, you can only see one of the carousel's boxes, and the Next and Previous buttons don't do anything. I've read up on event handling but still am lost with this carousel. I'd definitely appreciate help.

Code from JSFiddle...

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnPrevious">Previous</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnNext">Next</a>

<div class="carousel">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
        <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel {
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 357px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.carousel ul {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
}
.carousel ul li {
    position: absolute;
    height: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
    var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
    var clickCount = 0;
    var canClick = true;

    function numberOfElements() {
        var carWidth = carousel.parent().width();
        var elemWidth = carouselChild.width();
        return Math.floor(carWidth / elemWidth);
    }

    var moveWith = numberOfElements();

    itemWidth = carousel.find('li:first').width() + 1; //Including margin

    //Set Carousel width so it won't wrap
    carousel.width(itemWidth * carouselChild.length);

    //Place the child elements to their original locations.
    refreshChildPosition();



    //Set the event handlers for buttons.
    $(document).on('click', '.btnNext', function (event) {
        if (canClick) {
            canClick = false;

            //Animate the slider to left as item width 
            carousel.stop(false, true).animate({
                left: '-=' + itemWidth * moveWith
            }, 600, function () {
                //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                for (var i = 0; i < moveWith; i++) {
                    clickCount++;
                    lastItem = carousel.find('li:first');
                    lastItem.remove().appendTo(carousel);
                    lastItem.css('left', (((carouselChild.length - 1 + clickCount) * (itemWidth))));
                }
                //refreshChildPosition();
                canClick = true;
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btnPrevious', function (event) {
        if (canClick) {
            canClick = false;
            //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
            for (var i = 0; i < moveWith; i++) {
                clickCount--;
                lastItem = carousel.find('li:last');
                lastItem.remove().prependTo(carousel);
                console.log(itemWidth * (clickCount));
                lastItem.css('left', itemWidth * clickCount);
            }
            //Animate the slider to right as item width 
            carousel.finish(true).animate({
                left: '+=' + itemWidth * numberOfElements()
            }, 300, function () {
                canClick = true;
            });
        }
    });

    function refreshChildPosition() {
        carouselChild.each(function () {
            $(this).css('left', itemWidth * carouselChild.index($(this)));
        });
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have setup your bind events after ajax call and carousel inits.

Comment: Thank you. Will you please explain more about what I need to do?

Comment: Sure, when you describe bind actions before ajax call, your variables inside the code, not described yet so your animation actions will not work. Also if you push the click button, 'canClick' will be false and because of no animation finish function, will not be true again.